# Component size distribution in small Erdos-Renyi networks

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, graph-theory, random-graphs

I'm looking at $\mathcal{G}(n,p)$ (I'll call these Erdos-Renyi networks) where $n$ is, say, at most 10.

I would like to know the probability a random node is in a component of size $m$.

It's sufficient for me to know what the size distribution is of components in small Erdos-Renyi networks.  Is there a straight-forward calculation for this?

The best I can think of at the moment is to try to take all connected graphs of size $m\leq n$, and then determine their probability of being a component of an Erdos-Renyi network.  It's not obvious to me how to deal with this since I don't know a straightforward way to enumerate all connected graphs of size $m$ (though given such a connected graph, it's straightforward to calculate it's probability of being a component of an Erdos-Renyi network)

Comment: Note that the probability that some given connected graph $H$ is a component of $G(n,p)$ depends only on the number of vertices and edges.  So it is the counts that matter, not the graphs themselves, and that is a much easier task.

Comment: I fear most results on component size in ER graphs are for large $n$. But if $n$ is so small, then can't we enumerate all possible graphs with sampling probability, and their component size?

Answer (score 2):

The distribution of component size in Erdos-Renyi networks is discussed in many places, and known analytically. A recent reference that summarizes this is in Appendix A of

Eytan Katzav, Ofer Biham, and Alexander K. Hartmann,
[Distribution of shortest path lengths in subcritical Erdős-Rényi networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.05743), Phys. Rev. E 98, 012301 (2018).

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.   I've found: "A moment-generating formula for Erdős-Rényi component sizes"  https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ecp/1524708114  which gives a linear system of equations I can use.  The appendix you point to seems to work only as an approximation that is accurate in the large network limit below the giant component threshold.  In my case I need to be able to work in quite small networks.  I'm interested in, for example, being able to say for a graph of 20 nodes, what is the probability of a component of 6 nodes.  Can that be found from the paper you've linked?